# Azure Data Factory - copy Lookup activity output to json in blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

in ADF below is the output of my lookup activity (this the header of a flat file from SFTP)
{
"firstRow": {
"Prop_0": "000",
"Prop_1": "IN",
"Prop_2": "12123",
"Prop_3": "XYZ_ABC",
"Prop_4": "20211011",
"Prop_5": "034255",
"Prop_6": "272023"
}

Can someone help me the approach to transform this to a JSON file with custom field names instead of prop_x and save to a Blob storage

Answer (score 0):

You can simply leverage the additional column in a copy activity.

Follow your lookup activity by the copy activity:
[image]

In the source settings of the copy activity, add the new column names(i.e. the ones you expect in json). Here I used p0, p1...
Taking `p0` as example, you can simply put `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0` in the dynamic content.

[image]

Then in the Mapping tab, you just map to the target columns of your json file. (Assume you already import the schema of your target json)
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ray , but what should be the source dataset. in the normal copy activity flow, we will mention a blob/other as source, but in this case the data is flowing from lookup activity.

Comment: And is there any way to read only the first row (header) from blob file (flatfile, comma separated) and sink to other blob. And just FYI, The flow here I started as a lookup activity will read the first row and will save this to other blob path.

Comment: for the source dataset, I think you can just reuse your flat file to ensure there exists some record.

Comment: By "sink to other blob", you mean saving it as json file with only the renamed headers and empty values?

Comment: yes @ray, need to save headers in a json to a blob

Comment: It may be better for you to update your question with your sample output (i.e. the json you expected) to let us better understand your scenario and see how wr can help.